# Transposing a multi-dimensional matrix in Python with list comprehensions

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a Python assignment where I have to transpose a multi-dimensional matrix (3x3, 4x4,5x5...) without using any for-loops but only using list comprehension.

As an example for a 2x2 matrix, we have:

```
a2 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
n = len(a2)
print [[row[i] for row in a2] for i in range(n)]
```

But I am not sure I really understand how it works or how to adapt it for a 3x3, 4x4, 5x5... matrix

For instance, with

```
a3 = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

I don't necessarily want you to give me the answer (still have to figure out by myself), but any hint would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have there is a `2x2x2` ... I'm not sure what transposing actually means in that case ...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous -- You state "multi-dimensional" in the title, but then all the cases you say you want are 2-dimensional (`3x3`, `4x4`, `5x5` ...).  I'm guessing you want to scale the 2D case to arbitrary `n`, not do a n-dimensional transpose (because the latter case would require a rigourous definition of what the transpose actually means).

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I have to admit I haven't worked on matrixes for quite a while... nedd to brush my knowledge up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in for this - [the `zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> list(zip(*[[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Note that the call to `list()` is to show the result, in 3.x, this produces an iterable, not a list (which is lazy, giving memory benefits). In 2.x, it returns a list anyway.

If you want to transpose the internal parts as well in an example with more nested lists, then it's relatively simple to use a list comprehension to run `zip()` on the sublists.

Example in 2.x for ease of reading:

```
>>> zip(*(zip(*part) for part in [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]))
[((1, 3), (5, 7)), ((2, 4), (6, 8))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe it's the easiest solution! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you already have it in your example...

```
a2 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  #2x2
n = len(a2)
print [[row[i] for row in a2] for i in range(n)]

a2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]  #3x3
n = len(a2)
print [[row[i] for row in a2] for i in range(n)]
```

The object:

```
a3 = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

Is not a 2x2, or a 3x3 or a 4x4 -- It's a 2x2x2.  You'll need to explain exactly what a `transpose` means for that data structure.

As a side note, if you don't have the list-comprehension as a constraint, using `zip` as proposed by Lattyware is the way you should do this -- I'm only trying to point out that your solution already works for the `NxN` case.

Comment: -1, this is a bad way to transpose values. It only works on lists and is slower than `zip()`.

Comment: @Lattyware -- I agree that `zip` is **MUCH** better.  But this was written as a constraint of the assignment ("but only using list comprehension.").

Comment: He said no `for` loops, he never said no built-ins.

Comment: @Lattyware -- He said "but only using list comprehension" -- `zip` isn't a list comprehension ... It's silly that we're discussing this.  I've already conceeded that in the general case, `zip` is infinitely better, I'm just concerned with satisfying the constraints and pointing out to OP that the data structure `a3` doesn't have a meaningful transpose until he defines what that means ...

Comment: Neither is `range()`. I get what you are saying, but it appears to me that the *actual* problem here is transposing more deeply nested lists, which could be done with a list comprehension and `zip()`. I think that was probably the point of the exercise, but I admit it's pretty ambiguous. Either way, I'll remove my -1, as that may have been a bit much. Edit: Made an edit so I could remove my -1.

Comment: @Lattyware -- I'm glad we could come to an agreement here :-).  I never feel good when I have a disagreement with another user that I respect.  In any event, I've asked OP for clarification about what is actually requested.  I'll happily delete my answer if OP responds and my guess about what is required is incorrect.

Comment: Agreed, a clarification will make this clearer. Apologies for not thinking enough about the potential interpretations of the question - I'm always a bit quick to jump in, so please continue to call me out on it in future XD.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Feel free to keep calling me out as well.  I'm always happy to fix (or delete) my crappy answers ...

Comment: both answers are great. +1 and +1 for both.. . :)

Comment: Sorry, I guess the assignment wasn't formulated very clearly and therefore my question was a bit ambiguous. I'll keep this as an option if we are really supposed to ONLY use list comprehensions.